# How get data as array from DB to array variable in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

In database postgresql i have field as INTEGER[]. In there i have for example data like this: {2,3,55,122} When i take this data from DB

```
$rs = getData();
$abc = $rs['raw'];
var_dump($abc);
```

output is

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "{2,3,55,122}"
}
```

but i need data as array like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "2"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "3"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "55"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "122"
}
```

How can i do it from database layer or php. 
Is one way use trim and explode only ?

up
getData function in ZEND

```
private function getData(){
$select = $this->objDB->select()
->from(array('tb' => 'table'), array('raw',))
->where('id = 10');
return $this->select($select,true);
}
```

Comment: Post the `getData()` function or at least how you build your select query

Comment: i added getData function

Comment: Although for this question, you can handle it with PHP quickly. I think you'd better know more about how Array type in PostgreSQL works. For your references: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION

Comment: so maybe better will be create field as varchar not like integer[] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 2-step process that is easily solved with built in functions:

```
$abc = explode( ',' ,str_replace( array('{', '}') , '',$abc)) ;
```

Remove the brackets from the string then explode.

OR as you said you can use trim:

```
$abc = explode( ',' , trim($abc , '{}')) ;
```